# TCL/C - when is setFromAnyProc() called

Tags: c, tcl

I am creating a new TCL_ObjType and so I need to define the 4 functions, setFromAnyProc,  updateStringProc, dupIntRepProc and  freeIntRepProc. When it comes to test my code, I see something interesting/mystery.

In my testing code, when I do the following:

```
Tcl_GetString(p_New_Tcl_obj);
```

updateStringProc() for the new TCL object is called, I can see it in gdb, this is expected.

The weird thing is when I do the following testing code:

```
Tcl_SetStringObj(p_New_Tcl_obj, p_str, strlen(p_str));
```

I expect setFromAnyProc() is called, but it is not!

I am confused. Why it is not called?

Comment: I see that you have asked a number of questions. Have any of them been answered to your satisfaction? Please mark answers which _you_ find useful as being correct by clicking on the hollow check mark beside them. (A quick glance indicates that at the very least your questions on `std::vector` memory management and incrementing in a loop are adequately answered.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setFromAnyProc` is not nearly as useful as you might think. It's role is to convert a value[*] from something with a populated `bytes` field into something with a populated `bytes` field and a valid `internalRep` and `typePtr`. It's called when something wants a *generic* conversion to a particular format, and is in particular the core of the `Tcl_ConvertToType` function. You probably won't have used that; Tcl itself certainly doesn't!

This is because it turns out that the point when you want to do the conversion is in a type-specific accessor or manipulator function (examples from Tcl's API include `Tcl_GetIntFromObj` and `Tcl_ListObjAppendElement`, which are respectively an accessor for the `int` type[**] and a manipulator for the `list` type). At that point, you're in code that has to know the full details of the internals of that specific type, so using a generic conversion is not really all that useful: you can do the conversion directly if necessary (or factor that out to a conversion function).

`Tcl_SetStringObj` works by throwing away the internal representation of your object (with the `freeIntRepProc` callback), disposing of the old `bytes` string representation (through `Tcl_InvalidateStringRep`, or rather its internal analog) and then installing the new `bytes` you've supplied.

I find that I can leave the `setFromAnyProc` field of a `Tcl_ObjType` set to `NULL` with no problems.

---

<sup>[*] The `Tcl_Obj` type is mis-named for historic reasons. It's a value. `Tcl_Value` was taken for something else that's now obsolete and virtually unused.</sup>
<sup>[**] Integers are actually represented by a cluster of internal types, depending on the number of bits required. You don't need to know the details if you're just using them, as the accessor functions completely hide the complexity.</sup>